# IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream) corrupts file

Tags: java, android

I'm saving file from API call to local device storage using the following code

```
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
        .getContent();

if (null != inputStream) {
    File file = new File(path + filename);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    // Save the file locally.
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fos);

    // Close both streams
    fos.close();
    inputStream.close();

    Log.d(TestActivity.LOG_TAG, filename + " saved successfully: " +
            Boolean.toString(file.isFile()));
}
```

it saving the file to my device storage in given path but the file is corrupt.

Comment: Well in what way is it corrupt? Is it not the size you expect? Have you validated that you definitely received the data you expected? It sounds much more likely that the problem is with the data received than with a simple method to copy an input stream to an output stream. I'd also advise you to use a try-with-resources statement for both streams. (And personally to check `if (inputStream != null)` instead of the null-first comparison, just for readability...)

Comment: i copied the file to local from DDMS and its not opening it is actually a png file.

Comment: I have also check the url given by the server and it's opening/saving the file from browser

Comment: @JonSkeet also what do you mean by `try-with-resources statement `

Comment: But have you looked at what data you *have* got? Sure, it's not what you expected - but what *is* there? Is it the right data but with something extra at the start or end? Is it actually a textual error message? As for try-with-resources - Google it!